# Limit of $\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{2n})^n=\sqrt{e}$$

But I could not reason why this is, I know that I can rewrite it as

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{n})^n=\sqrt{e}$$

But I can't find any real calculation where it is actually calculated, and at least for me, it's not totally obvious.

Or in other words its not obvious why

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n=e^x$$

Maybe there is a link which I could not find, where the relation is explained. Many thanks.

Comment: The definition/identity $e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+x/n)^n$ is very well-known. See e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3137025/357390).

Comment: $$\sqrt e=e^{\frac12} .$$

Comment: Do you know that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n={e}$?

Comment: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{2n})^n$ now take $m=2n$, and obviously $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty} as \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$, so you get $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{m})^{m/2}$. I hope the rest of the logic is easy.

Comment: @ThomasShelby yes, i actually just understood the problem :) many thanks for your answer

Comment: @Ang Haven't you considered accepting an answer? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

Compute the limit of the log:
$$\ln\biggl(1+\frac1{2n}\biggr)^{\negthickspace n}=n\ln\biggl(1+\frac1{2n}\biggr)=\frac{\ln\biggl(1+\frac1{2n}\biggr)}{\frac1n}\sim_\infty\frac{\frac1{2\not n}}{\frac1{\not n}}=\frac12.$$

Answer (score 3):

Write your term in the form $$\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{2n}\right)^{1/2}$$

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments, consider the well-known identity

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(1+\frac{x}{n}\bigg)^n=e^x\tag1$$
Now let $x=\frac{1}{2}$ in order to obtain

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\bigg(1+\frac{1}{2n}}\bigg)^n=e^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt e$$

Now, if you want to understand the identity (1), you might want to check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882741/limit-of-1-x-nn-when-n-tends-to-infinity)

Comment: Thanks i was looking for a way to understand the identity :) many thanks for your help!

Comment: @Ang I'm glad I could help you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with this very famous limit:

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{r}{x}\right)^x=e^r
$$

You can find a very good proof of why it's equal to $e^r$ [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1617/MathMforCS/expfn.pdf).

Comment: Yeah i was looking for the proof :) many thanks for your answer!!